# A better way to introduce ordered pairs in ZF?

Tags: set-theory

Currently, a standard way to introduce ordered pairs in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (**ZF**) is to define
an ordered pair $(a,b)$ as $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. From this definition one can deduce the main property of ordered pairs:
$(a,b) = (x,y) \rightarrow a=x \,\, \& \,\, b=y$.

But some strange theorems can also be proved, for example, $(a,a) = \{\{a\}\}, \{a\} \in (a,b)$, etc.

So a natural question arises: is it possible to introduce ordered pairs in a more safe way, without possibility to get
such strange "theorems".

A possible answer may give the following statement:

Let $T$ be a (supposedly consistent) first-order theory,  let $T_1$ be an extension of $T$ by adding to (the language of) $T$
a new function symbol $f$ of arity $n$ and a new axiom $A$ in the language of $T_1$(a defining axiom for $f$),
let $K(v_1, \ldots, v_n$) be a term in the theory $T$, where $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are all free variables in $K$,
let $A_0$ be the result of replacement in the formula $A$ every occurrence of $f(a_1, ..., a_n)$, where $a_1, ..., a_n$ are
the arguments of $f$ in the current occurrence, with $K(a_1, ..., a_n)$.

Then $T_1$ is a conservative extension of $T$, if the formula $A_0$ is a theorem in $T$.

Proof

let $M$ be a model of $T$, let $M_1$ be an extension of $M$ by adding to $M$ the function $f^{M_1}$, which can be defined as
$\lambda(v_1, ..., v_n; K)$ - a kind of the untyped lambda notation is used.

It is easy to see that $M_1$ is a model of $T_1$.

Then $T_1$ is a conservative extension of T ( see Model Theory by Wilfrid Hodges, Cambridge University Press, 1994, p.66).

end of proof.

If $T$ is Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, $f$ is a function symbol of arity 2 for denoting ordered pairs (usually omitted),
the formula $A$ is $f(x,y) = f(x_1,y_1) \rightarrow x=x_1 \& y=y_1$, the term $K$ (it may be called the Kuratowski's term) is $\{\{x\}, \{x,y\}\}$,
then the formula $A_0$ is $\{\{x\}, \{x,y\}\} = \{\{x_1\}, \{x_1,y_1\}\} \rightarrow x=x_1 \& y=y_1$, which is a theorem in **ZF**.

Any comments ? Other approaches?

See also my similar question(and interesting answers to it) at:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4066257/

A different approach is described in the paper "Adding an Abstraction Barrier to ZF Set Theory"

https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-030-53518-6_6.pdf

An excerpt from it:

" Such ‘accidental theorems’ do not match how people think about the mathematics and also cause practical difficulties when using set theory in machine-assisted theorem proving."

Comment: There has been some work done on structural set theory with the goal of avoiding 'junk theorems' like this, you may want to have a google on it. In the particular case of ordered pairs this seems like a lot of work for a little payoff (good luck using this in an introductory set theory class), but the overall goal of avoiding all junk theorems is interesting I think.

Comment: You can expand the language of ZF by adding in new function/relation symbols for definable functions/relations, as you do here with the Kuratowski ordered pair. Sometimes this is useful, e.g. in Venturi & Viale's work in model companions for set theory ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.13372)). But for most cases where one is working with this level of detail, and not just handwaving things with "this can obviously be formalized in set theory", this makes extra work for little gain, which is why it's standard to formulate ZF in such a minimal language.

Comment: There are "strange" results in any structure that allows encodings.  Computer programs are encoded as strings of bits, and so are numbers.  Thus, it often makes sense to ask "What happens if we run a program, using its own string of bits as the input?"  In some ways, this might be a "strange" way to think about things, but after some consideration, you might change your mind and realize this leads to some interesting meta-results.  Turing, Godel, and others sure thought so.

Comment: There have been extensive discussions here and elsewhere about "junk theorems". The point is that @PaceNielsen is making is the correct one. The fact that I can treat a computer program as a very large number in the memory of my computer, and then ask what are its prime divisors does not take away from number theory and the natural numbers as a foundation for computability and computing.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4066257/can-a-notation-for-ordered-pairs-in-zfc-set-theory-be-introduced-as-a-conservati

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4066257/can-a-notation-for-ordered-pairs-in-zfc-set-theory-be-introduced-as-a-conservati

Comment: @Steve Not exactly. There I just asked, here I also gave an answer.

Comment: @Andrej Not exactly. There I just asked, here I also gave an answer

Comment: @Pace Talking about computer programming, there are abstract data types, which hide unessential details of concrete representations, helping to concentrate just on the algorithm. The same thing with ordered pairs: it is also should be  unessential which paring function used: Kuratowski's, Hausdorf's or Wiener's or else.

Comment: @VictorMakarov Sure you can hide unessential details.  And in some contexts it is good to do so.  But I personally think that introducing the idea of the Kuratowski encoding of ordered pairs to students is very important.  It helps later when they encounter other, harder, encodings (as well as helps them develop the know-how to avoid "strange" theorems).  In other words, I prefer leave the "hiding" to the user of the system, and not to the formal system itself.

Comment: Whatever we want of ordered pairs is absolutely not only the famous implication. I believe that (a,b) being Goedel-constructible in a,b is a sine qua non in set theoretic practice above 5 or so introductory lectures, and so is (a,b) being easily coded by a real provided a,b are reals, and zillion more such properties. So an abstract non-definable Bourbaki-style pair in the language will not work.

Comment: This is a situation where categorical thinking is really helpful: you should define "ordered pairs" by a universal property, run the usual argument to show that if they exist then they are unique up to a canonical isomorphism, and then use any construction you want to actually show that they exist.  You then only use the universal property when you prove results about them, so there are no "junk theorems".  This is basically what most mathematicians are doing when they talk about ordered pairs, whether or not they have it formalized in their head explicitly.

Comment: @Andrej I just added a link to the paper "Adding an Abstraction Barrier to ZF Set Theory" which states, in particular, ". Such ‘accidental theorems’ do not match how people think about the mathematics and also cause practical difficulties when using set theory in machine-assisted theorem proving." So I added the tag "proof assistants"

Comment: @VictorMakarov: You should not add the `proof-assistants` tag because your question does not mention proof assistants. If you think that proof assistants are relevant, then your question should make that explicit. For example, you might be suggesting that your proposal is a good way to introduce ordered pairs in a proof assistant (which one?). Think of it this way: someone browsing questions tagged "proof assistants" will have no idea why your questions is on the list.

Comment: What is wrong with junk theorems? Surely one should eat healthy food to stay healthy, but there is nothing wrong with eating junk food every now and then. (If you eat too much junk food, that could create some health problems, just like proving too many junk theorems as a part of your career would decrease your chance of being taken seriously...)

Comment: "Not exactly. There I just asked, here I also gave an answer" That just makes this *less of* a question than the MSE question. (Besides, in my opinion this really isn't MO-appropriate in the first place.)

Comment: @Burak Finally, someone else who appreciates junk theorems! :P

Comment: @Burak: The unicorn wore a suit of cow fingers. There, English has junk sentences. Must be a bad language...